# Converting Some PHP Header Code into Classic ASP

Tags: angularjs, json, vbscript, asp-classic, ionic-framework

I have 2 files:

1. Locally hosted project coded in Ionic/AngularJS trying to retrieve JSON from the ASP file.
2. External ASP File which outputs JSON data made out of database values from a query.

However, everytime my Angular code tries to call my externally hosted ASP file, I get the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mysite/mobile/api.asp. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I understand that I probably didn't code my header wrongly somewhere. This is how I am currently setting my headers in Classic ASP:

```vb
If Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ORIGIN") <> Null Or Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ORIGIN") <> "" Then
  Call AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ORIGIN"))
  Call AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  Call AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
End If

If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "OPTIONS" Then
  Call AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
  Call AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"))
  Call Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
End If
```

This does not work unfortunately, I've even tried just doing `Call AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` outside of the `If` statement; but to no avail.

Now this is the code in PHP which I am trying to emulate in ASP. I managed to retrieve JSON data successfully without getting header errors.

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
 }

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

   exit(0);
 }
```

So why don't I just use the PHP file if it works? My current host does not have PHP configured and to configure it, I would have to restart the server which is not an option since my site has continous database changes happening every few seconds.

I'm hoping someone can correct where I messed up the setting of Header in my ASP code.

Comment: Have you tried `Response.AddHeader` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I have, and to no avail. Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to this. I noticed that

```
Call Response.Addheader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

works for `$http.get` and it's fulfilling my need for now. So for those having trouble with `$http.post` can give `$http.get` a try.